# Issue with Branch Specifier in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, github, jenkins-plugins

I have 2 jobs in jenkins which are suppose to build from github

1. To run tests on dev branch when pull request is generated from dev to stage
   `Branch Specifier : */dev`
2. To run tests on stage branch when pull request is generated from stage to master branch
   `Branch Specifier : */stage`

But both the jobs are getting triggered whenever I generate a pull request from dev to stage or stage to master.

I have already tried using `refs/heads/<branchName>` in branch specifier and `+refs/heads/<branchName>:refs/remotes/origin/<branchName>` in Refspec

I am using Github pull request builder jenkins plugin

Can someone please help me to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

A build trigger to publish jenkins jobs upon receipt of a matching message. A builder that may additionally be used to submit a message to the subject matter upon the completion of a job. A post-build motion that may additionally be used to post a message to the subject upon the completion of a job.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. `whitelist target branches` option in Advanced section of `Github pull request builder` under `build trigger` helped in resolving this issue